# Heroku warnings in logs using django-celery

Tags: python, django, heroku, python-2.7, django-celery

I am trying to deploy my first app with heroku, and I keep running into issues. Essentially, now whenever I try to open my app with heroku open, I get the "Application Error" page telling me to check my logs. I successfully was able to get through the tutorial, but now following the same steps with my own project, I haven't had any luck.  As far as I can tell from the logs, the relevant warnings I am getting are:

```
WARNING/MainProcess] celery@ce7e5946-3bc3-4622-856f-863b49f442d4 ready
WARNING/Beat] Reset: Account for new version field
WARNING/Beat] Reset: Account for utc_enabled field
WARNING/Beat] Reset: Account for new tz field
```

The last three all seem to stem from the PersistentScheluler class within celery/beat.py, but I don't understand why. I have no idea about the first warning (or why that is even a warning). Any insight? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

have you tried to set DEBUG to True in Django settings ?

that should give you enough information about the error to fix it.